# How do i query the price between a start day/month and end day/month

Tags: php, mysql

The day is 4, the month is 10.
How do i query a price where the month is between the start_month and end_month range AND they day is also between a range?

The start_day, start_month, end_day and end_month can be variable in the database.

Screenshot of the database: 
[image: Database]

My current query:

`$price  = FrontendModel::getDB()->getVar('SELECT p.price FROM appartments_pricing as p
WHERE (p.days_start >= ? AND p.months_start >= ?) AND (p.days_end <= ? AND p.months_end <= ?) AND p.appartment_id = ?',
array($day,$month, $day, $month, $appartment_id));`

Comment: and what is wrong with your current query?

Comment: I never get the wanted result. The record with the price "15"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the day to lie *within* the range `days_start <= day <= days_end`, then you need to switch your query around (same goes for month):

```
$price = FrontendModel::getDB()->getVar('SELECT p.price FROM
appartments_pricing as p WHERE (p.days_start <= ? AND p.months_start <= ?) AND
(p.days_end >= ? AND p.months_end >= ?) AND p.appartment_id = ?',
array($day,$month, $day, $month, $appartment_id));
```

Comment: I have suspicion that this solution is incorrect. Try (9 Nov > 20 Oct). The month ( 11>10) will be true but the day comparison will fail (9>20). I'd suggest to use solution by @jancha

Comment: @romanish If we assume that "days_start months_start" is the start date, and "days_end months_end" is the end date then yes I agree jancha's solution is better. The question is vague, "where the month is between the start_month and end_month range AND they day is also between a range?" and doesn't really indicate whether or not start_day and start_month are related.

Answer (score 1):

okay another option:

```
mysql> select
           ap_id, price,
           date(concat('2000', '-', months_start, '-', days_start)) as start,
           date(concat('2000', '-', months_end, '-', days_end)) as end
           from x
           having date('2000-10-4') > start and date('2000-10-4') < end;

+-------+-------+------------+------------+
| ap_id | price | start      | end        |
+-------+-------+------------+------------+
|    32 |    15 | 2000-01-01 | 2000-12-31 |
+-------+-------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my database structure is different.
So your query will not work with mine. Or is it just not possible to do with my DB structure?

Comment: it is the same apart from ap_id. change it to appartment_id and that's it.

Comment: Not really, i have 2 extra columns.
I store the start day, start month, end day and end month separately.
But nachito gave we a working solution.

Comment: I know but look at query :) it creates  virtual  start/end fields by concatenating your other fields. and then using normal date comparison features.